# One Cassandra node fails to join the Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I'm configuring a three node Cassandra cluster which are located in three different machines. I can ping to one another, and ssh too. 
I have setup the cassandra cluster in these three machines. Say they are A, B, C where A is the seed. Here, C joins to the seed (A) successfully, and a joining log get printed. When I analyze the cluster via A, I can see that C has joined, and has 66.7% ownership. 'A' has 33.3% ownership. (I have equally divided the tokens.) 
But the node B didn't join the cluster. There is no errors printed. The configurations of B, and C are similar except for the listen_address , and rpc_address. I verified the config between these two, and they are similar.

This is probably an issue with network, but I'm not sure whether that's the case. There is no issue gets printed. Any suggestions on things I can try out here? This seems pretty strange. May be this is due to some port issue?

Comment: what is 'nodetool -h localhost ring' output on B?

Answer (score 0):

What Cassandra version are you on?

Try shutting down every node and bringing them up one by one. Cassandra prior to 1.1.6 (I think it was that point version) had a problem where nodes sometimes couldn't re-join the ring.

Secondly, make sure every node is configured with the same cluster name and with the same set of seed nodes.

Comment: We are using Cassandra 1.1.3. Anyway, we found the solution, and it turned out to be an issue with network interface. Each machine have two Network interfaces. ie. one on 192.168.x range, and other on 10.x range. The machine with issues turned out to be using a 10.x IP for rpc address. (We have a domain to ip mapping)
So, changing the IP fixed the issue. Would using 0.0.0.0 as rpc_address a possible solution here?

Comment: Yes - but the standard advice is to put them on different interfaces so that the gossip between the nodes doesn't get hit by large amounts of traffic from the clients.